# How to reuse reducers in redux toolkit with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a slice like this:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    ...initialUserInfo,
    ...initialBasicAsyncState,
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, { payload }: PayloadAction<{ userObj: User }>) => {
      const { id, email, googleId, facebookId } = payload.userObj;
      state.id = id;
      state.email = email;
      if (googleId) state.googleId = googleId;
      if (facebookId) state.facebookId = facebookId;
    },
    clearUser: (state) => {
      state.id = "";
      state.email = "";
      state.googleId = "";
      state.facebookId = "";
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder
      .addCase(getUser.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(getUser.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isSuccess = true;
        state.errors = null;
      })
      .addCase(getUser.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        if (action.payload) {
          state.errors = action.payload;
        } else if (action.error) state.errors = action.error;
      }),
});
```

I would like to write a reusable piece of code for the part which begins in the `extraReducers`, because I will have same async request handling in several slices. I read the docs, but still did not manage to understand how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interface CustomState {
  isLoading: boolean
  isSuccess: boolean
  errors: ValidationErrors | SerializedError | null
}

function apiReducerBuilder<T, U>(
  builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<CustomState>,
  customThunk: AsyncThunk<
    T,
    U,
    {
      rejectValue: ValidationErrors
    }
  >
) {
  return builder
    .addCase(customThunk.pending, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = true
    })
    .addCase(customThunk.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.isLoading = false
      state.isSuccess = true
      state.errors = null
    })
    .addCase(customThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.isLoading = false
      if (action.payload) {
        state.errors = action.payload
      } else if (action.error) state.errors = action.error
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => apiReducerBuilder(builder, getUser)
```

This will only work if you pass the same state type `Custom State`. And your typing are well established for the thunk. Or else you will have to declare the types when calling `apiReducerBuilder`

So, make sure that you always pass the same `Custom State` to your builder and Thunk or else it will not work.

**EDIT**

Maybe, you can extend your slice state type with Custom State type and it might just work. I haven't tried it. So, I'll leave it to you to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Still have not tried doing it the other way. Also wanted to ask, how would I add more async thunks (like getUser) from the same slice without creating another builder?

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/429 -> This might help you probably. Checkout the second last comment in particular using `isAnyOf`.
`builder.addMatcher(isAnyOf (tunkOne, thunkTwo), (state, action) => ...`

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#builderaddmatcher) which shows how to use `addMatcher` with type predicates like `action.type.endsWith('/pending')` to match any pending action.

I played with this a bit and one of the things that makes it hard is that the `builder` functions need to be called in a particular order: `addCase`, then `addMatcher`, then `addDefaultCase`.  So we cannot apply a bunch of `addMatcher` calls first and then use the `builder` normally.

The other hard part is knowing the `payload` type for `rejectWithValue` since the rejection value is not one of the generics on the `AsyncThunk` type (at least not directly).

The best solution that I came up with is to use a single `addMatcher` call to handle all three cases of the thunk.

---

These basic types and type guards are [copied from the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#builderaddmatcher).

```
type GenericAsyncThunk = AsyncThunk<unknown, unknown, any>

type PendingAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk['pending']>
type RejectedAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk['rejected']>
type FulfilledAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk['fulfilled']>

function isPendingAction(action: AnyAction): action is PendingAction {
  return action.type.endsWith('/pending')
}

function isRejectedAction(action: AnyAction): action is RejectedAction {
  return action.type.endsWith('/rejected')
}

function isFulfilledAction(action: AnyAction): action is FulfilledAction {
  return action.type.endsWith('/fulfilled')
}
```

The action matcher is a curried function that takes 1-to-many thunks and returns `true` if the action name starts with the `typePrefix` of any of those thunks.

```
const isThunk = <T extends AsyncThunk<any, any, any>[]>(...thunks: T) =>
  (action: AnyAction) => 
     thunks.some((thunk) => action.type.startsWith(thunk.typePrefix));
```

The case reducer handles all three cases of the thunk(s).  It calls the type guard functions to determine which type the `action` is and update the state accordingly.  We require that the `state` extends a type with the properties that we are updating.

```
type BasicAsyncState = {
  isLoading: boolean;
  isSuccess: boolean;
  errors: any;
};

const thunkHandler = <S extends BasicAsyncState>(
  state: Draft<S>,
  action: AnyAction
): void => {
  if (isPendingAction(action)) {
    state.isLoading = true;
  } else if (isFulfilledAction(action)) {
    state.isLoading = false;
    state.isSuccess = true;
    state.errors = null;
  } else if (isRejectedAction(action)) {
    state.isSuccess = false;
    state.isLoading = false;
    state.errors = action.error;
  }
};
```

You would use these two functions in the same block as your other builder callbacks.  Remember that `addMatcher` always needs to come after `addCase`.

```
// can match one thunk
.addMatcher(isThunk(getUser), thunkHandler)
// or multiple thunks
.addMatcher(isThunk(getUser, loadSomething), thunkHandler)
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0MRN)

Comment: Just tried this solution, but for some reason typescript is giving me this error: 
Line 11:51:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "]" which points to 
type PendingAction = ReturnType<GenericAsyncThunk["pending"]>

For what is worth, I am using the default CRA tsconfig.